# Testing features with specific time definitions

Tags: system-testing, timeout

I have a system which defines that after 5 minutes of x do y.
Currently I have system tests (preferably treating the system as black box as possible) which does x for 5 minutes and waits for y.

This of course makes the test very time consuming and multiplying it by many features of the kind or testing features with longer duration (let's say days) makes these kind of testing impractical.
What is considered the best way to test such features, automatically of course.

Comment: Other than fiddling with the system time (which I don't often recommend) I don't know of any other way to test time-dependent actions than to spend some time. Sometimes verbose logs with timestamps can make verifying many time-dependent actions simpler. BTW - you probably must also test that y *doesn't* occur when it shouldn't, right? For example, if you do x for 3 minutes and y occurs, that would be a bug?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - "For example, if you do x for 3 minutes and y occurs, that would be a bug?"  - Of course.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what exactly you're trying to get out of the test, but if the time element is merely a trigger for a particular behavior you might see if it can be mocked or stubbed out. So instead of waiting for the actual time to elapse, you could call some mock object to return the expected behavior after the time limit is reached without actually having to wait the full time. I'd be interested in hearing what you ultimately do to resolve this.

I agree that if it's actually a time dependent test, then you might just have to spend the time. Depending on how often you need to run those long running tests and depending on your framework, you might be able to tag the tests and group them separately from the non-time dependent tests. This way your test suite can be triggered to run the quick tests more often and the slow time-dependent tests less often (in case you're trying to get quick feedback for things like continuous integration).